# Are we graduating to a full site?

Tags: discussion

I saw [this question](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1705/design-concept-for-christianity-se), just a couple days old. Does this mean we are graduating to a full site now with the design work being done?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<strike>Eventually,</strike> YES. We are officially cleared to graduate, but that is a process not an instantatnious thing.

1. The design work isn't *done*, it's only a concept and Jin is still actively working on it. Once the design is finalized it also has to be implemented.
2. Once the design is implemented and goes live, other things steps will be put in gear. These are in no particular order and there is no particular timeline for them to happen within.

   - The beta moniker will be dropped and we'll be listed along with the full fledged sites where such lists break out beta sites separately.
   - We'll host regular elections and the pro-tem mods (such as myself) will be replaced with the winners of those elections.
   - We'll likely get our name a few special announcement and we'll have some promotional materials to work with (such as a logo if nothing else) that we can use in the process of declaring ourselves official instead of on parole.
   - Our site database will get added to the [SE Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I didn't mean the design work was *done*, as in final, I meant it was *being done*. My bad on that. Thanks

Comment: @SSumner Your English is slightly ambiguous on that point, and for the sake of other dropping by that aren't as up to speed on where we're at I thought clarification might be useful.

Comment: I agree it's ambigious. Clarification is no problem, I wasn't thinking carefully when I wrote it